# Error: illegal Verilog output port specification

Tags: verilog, output, input, error, testbench

I am having problems with my Verilog test bench. Every time I try to run it, I get the error in the title above for my four switch registers. I have searched this question numerous times, but I cannot find any answer that solves my problem.

```
// Module
module proj1 (A,B,C,D,a,b,c,d,e,f,g);
    
    input A,B,C,D;
    output a,b,c,d,e,f,g;
    wire w1,w2,w3;

    // For a/d/e/f/g outputs
    and(a , d , e , f , g , A , 1);
    
    // For a/d/e
    and(a , d , f , ~B , ~D);

    // For a
    and(a , C , 1);
    and(a , B , D);

    // For d
    xor(d , C , D);
    and(d , ~A , ~B);

    //For e/f   
    and(e , f , ~D , ~C);
    and(e , f , ~D , B);


    // For f/g
    and(f , g , B , ~C);

    // For f is above in the section For e/f
    and(g , C , ~D);
    and(g , C , ~A , ~B);
    



    // For b/c outputs
    and(b , c , ~B , ~C , ~D);
    
    // For b
    xnor(w2 , C , D);
    or(w3 , ~B , w2);
    and(b , w3 , ~A);

    // For c
    // w1 is the output of the below or expression so it can be used in the
    // following and expression
    or(w1 , ~C , D , B);
    and(c , ~A , w1);

endmodule 



// Test bench

module testbench4proj1();
    
    reg [3:0] switches;
    wire [6:0] leds;

    proj1 pr1(leds[6] ,leds[5] ,leds[4] ,leds[3] ,leds[2] ,leds[1] , leds[0], switches[3] , switches[2] , switches[1] , switches[0]);
    
        initial
            begin
                switches = 0000;
                $display("numbers:n     switches=ABCD   leds=abcdefg\n");
                #80 $finish;
            end

        always
            begin
                #10 $display("%h    " , switches , "%b  " , switches ,"     ", leds);
                switches = switches + 0001;
            end

endmodule
```

Comment: Try specifying switches and then leds in your testbench: `proj1 pr1(switches[3]..... ,leds[6].....)`

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in connecting up to your `proj1` module.  You should not try to drive your module output ports from your testbench.
The following will drive your inputs from the testbench:

```
proj1 pr1(switches[3] , switches[2] , switches[1] , switches[0], leds[6] ,leds[5] ,leds[4] ,leds[3] ,leds[2] ,leds[1] , leds[0]);
```

It is a better practice to use connection-by-name instead of connection-by-order.  Refer to the free IEEE Std 1800-2012, 23.3.2.2 *Connecting module instance ports by name*.